# Angular 2 Material Progress Bar not Showing up when using in template?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material

I am trying to incorporate Angular 2 Progress bar to my Angular App.

I am using Webpack as bundling tool .

I have started the Project with this Angular seed please find the git repo link of the seed

```
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
```

I have installed all the dependencies but still the Progress bar  doesn't show up.

component file

```
<div class="loading-overlay" *ngIf="loading">
  <!-- show something fancy here, here with Angular 2 Material's loading bar or circle -->
  Here
  <md-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-bar>
</div>
```

ngModule

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    routing,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],

})
```

Please Help

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Please elaborate on what is happening, and what should be happening

Comment: the progress bar is not appearing ,this is what the title says, its not appearing in the browser

Comment: Please down vote after getting to know the Full question i  gave the header as progress bar is now working the bar is not showing up

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens if you remove the [ ] from your import definition?

Comment: i am not getting error in the console, only i get a warning in the console Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly. But Hammer js is not required for md progress bar i know .Even removed the [] from import def no error

Comment: Then only reason is `loading` == false

Comment: Even if i remove loading same it just dosent show up

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the below css files referred in your index.html

[image]

In your webpack.config.js, under the app section check if the below line exists

```
'@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
```

You can also refer a cdn for @angular/material as below

```
'@angular/material': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/iht41sQH6tmCNqZu16dS?p=preview)**

Comment: This is not working , Please refer to this PR in git https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/1827/files/2cf0e2e8500584b5e4e90fa5908777b982dba584 . It clearly states that we have to do this configuration in Systemjs not in webpack. I have also mentioned the starter pack i am using.

Comment: @INFOSYS In this path `npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js` you are missing **bundles** folder

Comment: How to add it to the repo i am using , i have already installed material using npm .

Comment: which repo? first try in your local machine and see if it is working

Comment: I am working in my local machine itself but for starting up the project. I used https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter repo from git. It was mentioned in the question. Not able to find the path there which u mentioned.

Comment: You have node_modules?Inside that check for the file which I m pointing to material.umd.js

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply, There is no such File in my node module, Even in my node module there is no folder named material/bundles. Now how to add that? , i did install it using npm though even saved it usign -- save.

Comment: Then Use  CDN as in the screenshot and add to config.js

Comment: But there is no app section in my webconfig.js . If you check that Starter pack you will get to know , i know i am sounding silly but it isn't there  where to add.If you want i can add it in the question but (better if you check in that starter pack) it wont be a question according to stack standards

Comment: Did you get a chance to check

Comment: my bad I m sorry. it is map section!

Comment: Please Check on this link https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and let me know ehere to add i am confused literally sorry but thanks for all the work you have put in . But if you can be a bit specific as i dont know webpack configurations

Answer (score 0):

As @Christopher Moore pointed out, try removing the brackets around

```
[MaterialModule.forRoot()]
```

in imports. If this doesn't fix your issue, please provide additional information.

Comment: already did that to no avail, what is it more that you wamt me to add, i already mentioned the starter pack i am using.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code: 
**First of you import it on your app.module.ts**

import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    MatProgressBarModule
     ]

})

[You must have to import angular api](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/api)

Comment: please add some explanations to your answer for better understanding

Answer (score -1):

I cloned the webpack starter repository and got the progress bar to work the whole process was:

- clone the repository
- npm install + npm install -save @angular/material
- Add material Code, see below
- npm run build:prod
- npm run server:prod

Material code:
In app.module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

In app.module.ts @NgModule imports section add:

```
MaterialModule.forRoot()
```

In one of the component templates add:

```
<md-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-bar>
```

In the global styles file, e.g. "src/styles/styles.scss", add one of the themes as described below

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/purple-green.css';
```

From [official docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

> Angular Material comes prepackaged with several pre-built theme css
>   files. These theme files also include all of the styles for core
>   (styles common to all components), so you only have to include a
>   single css file for Angular Material in your app.
>
> You can include a theme file directly into your application from
>   @angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt
>
> If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line
>   in your styles.css file:
>
> @import
>   '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';

Comment: i need the whole Angular Material Package actually as i was trying to use the md-progress-bar but it just dosent show up and even there is no error in console .

Comment: I tried adding it to styles.scss but it dosent work out . This is not the error i guess .

Comment: i gues the error is due to the fact that the material package is missing not because of style

Comment: I cloned the repository and got it to work. See updated answer for the steps I took. Based on your comments, I don't think the issue is that the material package is missing because your import statement in the app.module.ts wouldn't work if it was. My suggestion is to check for conflicting styles in the loading-overlay class. Try move the md-progress-bar outside so that no other classes are applied to it.

Comment: MaterialModule.forRoot() throws error for me: ERROR in C:/.../app.module.ts (36,20): Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof MaterialModule'.

Comment: The most helpful thing for me was the `MaterialModule` as I had a common component using it, but had not included that module in the common package.